# Ember building form with views. Transfering view data array to application controller and then saving it

Tags: view, ember.js, has-many

Im trying to have a field where u can duplicate a field and add another data in it
E.g a person has a job and some data related to the job, then theres a button to add another workplace

Which would end up like this: 1: Job.scientist in an university 2: Job.teacher in a school and in the end of the form submit button. Right now ive come up with this. No clue if im even doing this the right way.

```
HBS>{{#each view.anotherField}}
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="view.message"}}
    {{/each}}
    <br/>
    <button {{action 'moreFields' target='view'}}> click for another field </button>
    <button {{action 'moreFields'}}> Save the thingy </button>
```

And the JS

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    message: '',
    anotherField: [{name: 'testname'}],
    content: [{inputvalues: 'test value'}],

    actions: {

      moreFields: function(){
          this.get('anotherField').pushObject({name: ''});
          //input contents
          var something = this.get('message');
          // input content array
          this.get('content').pushObject({name: something});
          // log array out on each click
          console.log(this.get('content'));

      }

    }
```

**And here is the JSBIN : http://jsbin.com/iSUdiCaX/3/edit**

Duplicating fields works nicely. ember creates fields with unique IDS. Also i can get the data inside the input fields and put it in an array, so this is pretty nice right:P Now there should be a way to open this array in application controller. HOW? And then save array one by one to model : which has a relation of hasMany ??   Not even sure if on the right path if

Cheers,

Kristjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the view, you can get the controller, and send an action to it

```
this.get('controller').send('addPerson', content);
```

http://jsbin.com/iSUdiCaX/6/edit

Comment: Thanks again kingpin !! =) Btw do u think im on the right path doing hasmany ? :)

Comment: As far as im concerned i can now map this array and save one by one :P